# create jQuery validation and redirect page to other address

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate, jquery

How is create a jQuery validation that after click on button submit page redirect to a other address?
Please give me a example, of each jQuery validation,(like:Empty field(input))

With respect

Comment: What does validation have to do with redirection? What do you want to validate? When do you want to redirect? Where? Why?

Comment: This is not a proper question. We are not here to build your sites for you - we are here to help us all overcome genuine issues, and in particular where some effort has been put in.

Comment: This question isn't specific enough for us to really help you. If you can slim it down and give us some specifics we may be able to get you on the right track. As it stands, you're asking for something too vague for anyone to pin down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to redirect to another page:

```
window.location.href = '/another-page';
```

As far as the validation is concerned I would very strongly suggest you looking at the [jquery validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). It's the *de-facto* standard for performing client side validation of HTML forms for people that don't want to reinvent the wheel.

So for people whiling to reinvent the wheel, here's what they could do:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myform').submit(function() {
        var myField = $('#myInput').val();
        if (myField == '') {
            alert('my field is required');
            return false;
        }
        // at this stage we know tat the form is valid as the user
        // filled the required myField. Now we can redirect
        window.location.href = '/another-page';
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: @Mehd S, you don't need jquery in order to redirect to another page. Simply set the `window.location.href` property to the new location as shown in my example. This is native javascript. As far as the jquery validation plugin is concerned, the documentation contains numerous examples. Or you mean you don't want to use any plugins and you want to reinvent wheels?